# Insert id value from 1 table into the other after creating a row VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

Now The Error thrown is at my Insert Statement. I cant figure out where it is. I have used the demo to fit my program but fails at the end. Here is the reworked code. 
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

```
Private data As New DataSet

Private connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TholusizoMoneyS.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")

Private WithEvents CustomerDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Customer", connection) With {.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey}
Private WithEvents LoanDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Loan", connection) With {.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey}

Private CustomerCommandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.CustomerDataAdapter) With {.QuotePrefix = "[",
                                                                                        .QuoteSuffix = "]"}
Private LoanCommandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.LoanDataAdapter) With {.QuotePrefix = "]",
                                                                                .QuoteSuffix = "]"}





Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        LoadSchema()
        ConfigureAutoIncrements()
        ConfigureRelation()
        LoadData()
        BindData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error")
    End Try
End Sub




Private Sub CustomerDataAdapter_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs) Handles CustomerDataAdapter.RowUpdated
    If e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
        Using Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", Me.connection)

            e.Row("CustomerID") = CInt(Command.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoanDataAdapter_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs) Handles LoanDataAdapter.RowUpdated
    If e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
        Using Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", Me.connection)
            e.Row("LoanID") = CInt(Command.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub SaveToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripButton.Click
    If Me.Validate() Then
        Me.CustomerBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.LoanBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.CustomerDataAdapter.Update(Me.data, "Customer")
        Me.LoanDataAdapter.Update(Me.data, "Loan")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub LoadSchema()
    Me.CustomerDataAdapter.FillSchema(Me.data, SchemaType.Source, "Customer")
    Me.LoanDataAdapter.FillSchema(Me.data, SchemaType.Source, "Loan")
End Sub

Private Sub ConfigureAutoIncrements()
    ConfigureAutoIncrement(Me.data.Tables("Customer").Columns("CustomerID"))
    ConfigureAutoIncrement(Me.data.Tables("Loan").Columns("LoanID"))

End Sub

Private Sub ConfigureAutoIncrement(ByVal Column As DataColumn)
    With Column
        .AutoIncrement = True

        .AutoIncrementSeed = 0

        .AutoIncrementStep = -1

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ConfigureRelation()
    Me.data.Relations.Add("TholusizoMoneyS",
    Me.data.Tables("Customer").Columns("CustomerID"),
        Me.data.Tables("Loan").Columns("CustomerID"),
        True).ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade
End Sub

Private Sub LoadData()
    Me.CustomerDataAdapter.Fill(Me.data, "Customer")
    Me.LoanDataAdapter.Fill(Me.data, "Loan")
End Sub

Private Sub BindData()
    Me.CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = Me.data.Tables("Customer")
    Me.LoanBindingSource.DataMember = "TholusizoMoneyS"
    Me.LoanBindingSource.DataSource = Me.CustomerBindingSource

    Me.CustomerDataGridView.DataSource = Me.CustomerBindingSource
    Me.LoanDataGridView.DataSource = Me.LoanBindingSource

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that SO frowns on answers with just links but I created a demo project to show how to do what you want and uploaded it elsewhere some time ago specifically so that I wouldn't have to keep showing the same thing over and over.  Here's a link to that project:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert

Comment: Please check the code as per your demo. It tells me that I have an incorrect Insert Statement. Please help find the bug

Comment: If you're using a command builder and you get a syntax error in one of the generated SQL statements then it generally means that one or more of your column names are reserved words or contain spaces or other special characters.  Try setting the QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix properties of the command builder to "[" and "]" respectively so that all your column names get wrapped in brackets.

Comment: It now works 100%. It's amazing how a struggle of 3 weeks could be solved in just few minutes. Thanks a million. Please post a video also on youtube. I am not the only one who suffered but thousands I guess.

Comment: Everything's easy when you know how.  While that use of QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix will work, it's always best to avoid using reserved words, spaces and other special characters in column names to begin with.  Do that if you possibly can.